# Jquery: Set width of frame

Tags: jquery, css, width, attr

I am trying to reduce the width of frame-table so that the position of right arrow will change after I click on the #circle2 button.

$("#frame-table").css({"width":'30px'}) does not work.

```
#frame-table{
 position: absolute;
 width:634px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

<div class="col-md-2" id="category"> 
    <center>
       <a href="#"><div class="img-circle" id="circle2">Mobile</div></a>         
    </center>
</div>    

<div class="col-md-7">   
    <div > 
        <table id = "frame-table">
            <tr>
                <td id = "left1">
                    <img src="img/left.png" alt = "left"/>
                </td>
                 <td id = "right1">
                     <img src="img/right.png" alt = "right"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
        <img class="img" src="img/web1.png" alt="Chania">  
    </div>

<div class="col-md-3">
</div>

$("#circle2").click(function(){ 
    $("#portfolio>li>img").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(/[^\/]*?(?=\d+.png)/, "mobile"));
    });
    $(".img").css({"width":'330px', 'height':'475px'}); 
    $(".img").attr("src", "img/mobile1.png"); 
    $("#category").after("<div class='col-md-2' id='space'></div>"); 
    $('.col-md-7').attr('class','col-md-5');
    //$("#frame").css({"width":'30px', 'height':'475px'}); 
    $("#frame-table").css({"width":'30px'});  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$("#frame-table").css("width", "330px");
```

Comment: I tried but it does not work. After click on the 'mobile' button,  the position of right arrow is suppose to move to the left. https://jsfiddle.net/tangjeen/5eker83t/1

Answer (score 3):

use

```
 $('#frame-table').attr('width', 30);
```

Comment: I tried but it does not work. After click on the 'mobile' button,  the position of right arrow is suppose to move to the left. http://jsfiddle.net/tangjeen/5eker83t/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#frame-table").width( 30 );
```

Comment: I tried but it does not work. After click on the 'mobile' button,  the position of right arrow is suppose to move to the left. https://jsfiddle.net/tangjeen/5eker83t/1